# SpringMVC on Heroku won't persist with DataBase

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-mvc, heroku

I am just starting with a Spring Application on Heroku. Till now everything seems to be working pretty fine, but I cant add anything to the Database. I am not sure if I need to change anything in the WebInterface at Heroku or at my Configurationfiles?

I can connect to my DB and also my Queries work (no Exception though), but the Result of the Query is empty.

If I call the `addBooking()` from the Service, the new Booking won't get written to the DB (As far as I can tell). The Query in `getAvailableBookings()` does not get any entries.

Maybe you will be able to find any mistake or am I missing anything?

MyServiceImpl:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.stuttgart.fahrrad.controller.BookingController;
import org.stuttgart.fahrrad.model.Booking;

import com.example.model.Person;

@Service
public class BookingServiceImpl implements BookingService {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BookingServiceImpl.class.getName());

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void addBooking(Booking booking) {

        logger.info("Persisting a booking to the DB!");

        em.persist(booking);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public int getAvailableBookings(Date bookingDay) {
        CriteriaQuery<Booking> c = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Booking.class);
        Root<Booking> from = c.from(Booking.class);
        return em.createQuery(c).getResultList().size();
    }
```

My applicationContext:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.stuttgart.fahrrad" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    </bean>

    <beans profile="default">
        <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource"/>        
        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="prod">
        <bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
            <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
            <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
            <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
            <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <!-- change this to 'verify' before running as a production app -->
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>

</beans>
```

Comment: You do not have `@Transactional` applied to your method(addBooking).

Comment: @BorisTreukhov Oh my ... This fixed ... How could I be this blind? Thank you like a trillion times!

Comment: @BorisTreukhov I would love to accept this answer. Please feel free to add it as an regular answer.

Comment: done, but tbh I have no ideas what to add to make it more interesting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have `@Transactional` applied to your addBooking method.